# Lighttpd FASTCGI varying instances by path

Tags: fastcgi, lighttpd

I have a multi-tenanted application where each tenant's data is in a separate database.

I want to implement FASTCGI programs under LIGHTTPD, but I want different instances of the program for each database.

For example, I would like any connection `{site}/app/c123/a/b` to be routed to instances of the FASTCGI app connected to database C123, and any connection `{site}/app/c578/a/b` to be routed to instances connected to database C578.

For startup purposes, assume that the FASTCGI app takes a startup parameter (ie, `-Dc123` or `-Dc578`) to select the database which it opens.

The /a/b are placeholders for elements of the path that will be passed through to any of the FASTCGI instances, regardless of the database to which it is connected. For example, `{site}/app/c123/Accounts/List` might return a list of accounts which are contained in the C123 database.

To support expected concurrency by tenant, I might want two instances of the app connected to database C123, eight instances of the app connected to database C578, and so on for different databases.

So, given these examples, what configuration of LIGHTTPD do I need such that 1..n instances of the FASTCGI app may be started for each database?

Answer (score 0):

You can run separate backend daemons for each user

[lighttpd mod_fastcgi](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModFastCGI)

[PHP-FPM](https://php-fpm.org/)

Alternatively, you can run a single backend and have it manage connecting to different database, as appropriate.